# create2 angle (packet ID 20)

Tags: irobot-create

how to convert the value you get for the angle (packet ID 20) into degrees?
i am using the create2 robot and when I did not understand the data I am getting back. The documentation it says it's in degrees but what I get back is a huge number like 4864 when I turned the robot just 45 degrees.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the `Distance` opcode (packet ID 19) has a [known bug](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/6869/roomba-create-2-problem-reading-distance-traveled) in it.  So I wouldn't be surprised if this also affects the `Angle` packet.  I would recommend using the `Left Encoder Counts` and `Right Encoder Counts` opcodes (packets 43 and 44) and compute the angle yourself.

The angle is pretty easy to calculate from the distances traveled by each wheel.  [This document](http://chess.eecs.berkeley.edu/eecs149/documentation/differentialDrive.pdf) has a good introduction to mobile robot kinematics.  But simply:

$$
\theta = \frac{d_r - d_l}{l}
$$

Where $d_r$ and $d_l$ are the distances traveled by the right and left wheels respectively since the last time step.  And $l$ is the wheel base of the robot.  The wheel base, number of encoder ticks per revolution, and wheel diameter can be found in the [OI Spec](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/create_2_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf).

Regarding units, the units for $d_r$, $d_l$, and $l$ shouldn't matter as long as they are all the same.  $\theta$ is in radians.  Picking mm for the lengths is easy because that is what is specified in the spec.  The wheel base is 235.0 mm.  To determine mm traveled from encoder ticks, I find it easiest to think about as a unit conversion using the equation for circle circumference.  If you have $X$ ticks:

$$
d \text{ (mm)} = X \text{ (ticks)} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1 \text{ (revolution)}}{508.8 \text{ (ticks)}} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\pi 72.0 \text{ (mm)}} {1 \text{ (revolution)}} \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. packet 43&44 give you  raw  encoder counts does the equation above cares about units? also I am not sure how to calculate the wheel base give the encoder ticks /rev and wheel diameter. can you please shed more light on this? thanks a million

Comment: See expanded answer.